# Disease Maps by using R

Tags: r, ggplot2

here my data set is attached in .csv file. Can some body help me in making the disease maps by using ggplot2 in R.

Thanks

```
Towns         Observed  Expected Latitude   Longitude
Jarawala Town   183 34.584  31.33429    73.419487
Sumindri Town   59  5.6927  31.0690531  72.9361303
Tandiawala Town 28  2.8326  31.0316667  73.1316667
Jhumra Town 23  1.0923  31.5666667  73.1833333
Madina Town 127 21.95   31.4178652  73.120208
Iqbal Town  40  6.9147  31.4932177  73.1051778
Jinnah Town 43  16.89   31.4144303  73.0768364
Layyalpur Town  97  38.121  31.4401011  73.0680131
```

Comment: Please post your data in an easily reproducible format, show what you have tried so far, and describe where you're presently stuck.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service. You need to show some effort in writing the code yourself before you can expect any assistance from us. As it stands your question is likely to be voted down and closed as not providing enough information.

Comment: Perhaps CartoDB - https://cartodb.com/ - would be better for you than R

Answer (score 7):

While I generally agree that SO is "not a free code writing service", this problem is extremely simple, and illustrates how easily one can implement fairly complex visualization in R. I am also acutely aware of how difficult it is to get started in R. So I suggest you use this *as a starting point*, study the code, read the documentation on the various functionality used, and extend it *yourself*.

[image]

```
library(rgdal)                            # for readOGR(...)
library(RColorBrewer)                     # for brewer.pal(...)
library(ggplot2)

setwd("< directory with all your files >")
pak <- readOGR(dsn=".",layer="PAK_adm3")  # map of Pakistan
map <- pak[pak$NAME_3=="Faisalabad",]     # extract Faisalabad region
centroids <- data.frame(coordinates(map)) # label(s) for the polygons
colnames(centroids) <- c("long","lat")
centroids$name <- map@data$NAME_3
palette <- brewer.pal(9,"YlOrRd")         # Yellow-Orange-Red color palette
ggplot(map)+
  geom_path(aes(x=long,y=lat,group=group))+
  geom_text(data=centroids, aes(x=long,y=lat, label=name))+
  geom_point(data=data,aes(x=Longitude,y=Latitude,size=Observed,color=Observed))+
  scale_color_gradient(low=palette[5],high=palette[9])+
  scale_size(guide="none")+
  theme_bw()+coord_fixed()
```

**Explanation**

All of your data is from the Faisalabad region in Pakistan, as far as I can tell. So first we need a map of Pakistan. This is available from a number of sources, but I prefer the outstanding [Global Administrative Areas](http://gadm.org/) website, where you can download the Pakistan shapefiles [here](http://biogeo.ucdavis.edu/data/gadm2/shp/PAK_adm.zip). These are, of course, in a zip archive, so you must unzip the files into a directory (noted in the code as "directory with all your files"). From there the workflow is:

```
 1. Read shapefile: pak <- readOGR(...) 
 2. Extract the appropriate region: map <- pak[...]
 3. Extract region name and centroid (for the label)
 4. Generate color palette: palette <- brewer.pal(...)
 5. Render the map, with points overlaid.
```

**EDIT** It has been brought to my attention that there is a direct interface to GADM in R, which avoids downloading and extracting the shapefiles manually. This uses the [`getData(...)`](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/raster/docs/getData) function in package `raster`.

```
# setwd("< directory with all your files >")
# pak <- readOGR(dsn=".",layer="PAK_adm3")  # map of Pakistan
library(raster)
pak <- getData("GADM",country="PAK",level=3) # map of Pakistan, admin level 3.
```

Comment: from where I can download the shapefile of the district Faisalabad according to eight towns of Faisalabad?

Comment: according to my aim of study I have to draw the choropleth map of the district Faisalabad to check the prevalence of disease in the towns of Faisalabad.

Comment: So you need the town boundaries in Faisalabad. This is admin level 4 I believe, whereas GADM goes only to level 3 for Pakistan. There is a level 4 shapefile [here](http://www.pakresponse.info/MapDataCenter/GISData.aspx), but it does not appear to include Faisalabad. The data clearly exists, as it was used to create [this image](http://www.auick.org/database/training/2007-1/CR/imgFaisalabad/map02.gif). My advice would be to contact the [Aisian Urban Information Center](http://www.auick.org/database/training/2007-1/CR/WS2007-1CR-Faisalabad.html) and see if they'll share it with you.